# when i add sqflite to any project and run it on my device or emulator i facing proplem when u remove sqflite the project flutter run

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, sqflite, sqf

Target kernel_snapshot failed: ProcessException: Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software.

Command: C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --disable-dart-dev C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\snapshots\frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --target=flutter --no-print-incremental-dependencies -Dflutter.inspector.structuredErrors=true -DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true -DFLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL=https://www.gstatic.com/flutter-canvaskit/0545f8705df301877d787107bac1a6e9fc9ee1ad/ -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --no-link-platform --packages "D:\my flutter projects\abdulaah_mansour.dart_tool\package_config.json" --output-dill "D:\my flutter projects\abdulaah_mansour.dart_tool\flutter_build\b92ccc9c4cdab31224fb4da1c9b761ff\app.dill" --depfile "D:\my flutter projects\abdulaah_mansour.dart_tool\flutter_build\b92ccc9c4cdab31224fb4da1c9b761ff\kernel_snapshot.d" --incremental --initialize-from-dill "D:\my flutter projects\abdulaah_mansour.dart_tool\flutter_build\b92ccc9c4cdab31224fb4da1c9b761ff\app.dill" --source file:///D:/my%20flutter%20projects/abdulaah_mansour/.dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart --source package:flutter/src/dart_plugin_registrant.dart -Dflutter.dart_plugin_registrant=file:///D:/my%20flutter%20projects/abdulaah_mansour/.dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart --verbosity=error package:abdulaah_mansour/main.dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

i try to update version of sql